# how to drawing shapes in google map (1 or more) using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, google-maps

i'm using google map to draw shapes
but i get error when i'm trying to get lat and lng from database and assign it to map

i have format data correctly after get it from database

```
for (var s = 0; s < array_points.length; s++) {
    var shapeCoordinates = array_points[s];
    var shap = Array();
    for (var sh = 0; sh < shapeCoordinates.length; sh++) {
        shap.push({lat: shapeCoordinates[sh]['lat'], lng: shapeCoordinates[sh]['lng']});

        var drawingManager = new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths: shap,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.35
        });
    }
}
```

i get the following error

```
Uncaught InvalidValueError: at index 0: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number
```

array_points have 3 shapes

shapeCoordinates have coordinates of the shape

Comment: What's the content of `shapeCoordinates[sh]['lat']`?

Comment: Despite of the error, `var drawingManager = new google.maps.Polygon({ ...` must be outside the `for` loop

Comment: shapeCoordinates have coordinates of the shape

Comment: Please show us an output of the variable, since I think the issue is there.

Comment: @antonio i'm trying it but i get the same error:

Comment: here you will fine the image explain the result
http://imgur.com/JpxmjDf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please convert this variable to integer it will solve your issue.

```
 parseFloat(shapeCoordinates[sh]['lat'])
```

Comment: thank  you
i'm trying 
<pre> parseFloat(shapeCoordinates[sh]['lat'])</pre>

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this**

```
for (var s = 0; s < array_points.length; s++) {
    var shapeCoordinates = array_points[s];
    var shap = [];
    for (var sh = 0; sh < shapeCoordinates.length; sh++) {
        shap.push({lat: shapeCoordinates[sh]['lat'], lng: shapeCoordinates[sh]['lng']});
    }
        var drawingManager = new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths: shap,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.35
        });
    drawingManager.setMap(map);    
}
```

Comment: @JihadMahfouz Please show me shapeCoordinates.length and shapeCoordinates array value

Comment: @JihadMahfouz You draw 1 Polygon?? or multiple